# writing unit test with jasmine angular

Tags: angular

I am working on a angular project and I am trying to write a unit test for this method:

```
 showDocuments(): boolean {
        return this.case && this.case.documentList &&
            this.case.documentList.hasDocuments() || !this.case.documentList.isSucceeded;
    }
```

Until now I have this for the test:

```
it('should show document', () => {
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
    });
```

Thank you

and this is the

```
DocumentListModel


import { DocumentModel } from 'afw/models';

/**
 * The model for documents that contains information about all the documents of the user
 * and document store queue for particular case number.
 */
export class DocumentListModel {

    /**
     * Indicator of how many documents there are in the queue
     */
    documentsInQueue?: number;

    /**
     * The actual documents
     */
    documents: Array<DocumentModel>;

    /**
     * Whether the DMS succeeded
     */
    isSucceeded: boolean;

    /**
     * Whether there is anything to display
     */
    hasDocuments() {
        return this.isSucceeded && this.documents && this.documents.length > 0 || this.documentsInQueue > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    constructor(item?: DocumentListModel) {
        if (item) {
            Object.assign(this, item);
        }
    }
}
```

There is a document and that document can have zero or more attachments

Comment: What are you trying to test? You did not actually ask a question? do you expect someone to write a generic test for you?

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: The .spec you show is not actually trying to test the method you indicated you want tested.  If you attempted to write this yourself, please show all the details of that.  [Try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Creating a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53208509) would be even better.

Comment: If you have no idea where to start, read the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing)